# Static Function Call's Result in HEREDOC

Tags: php, static-methods, heredoc

I just tried the following:

```
<?php
$script = <<<HEREDOC
    var delUrl = '{ScriptManager::getDelUrl()}';
HEREDOC;

echo $script;
?>
```

And in the browser I get:

```
// Used by JS
var delUrl = '{ScriptManager::getDelUrl()}';
```

Instead of seeing the result of the static call `ScriptManager::getDelUrl()` the output is the literal PHP. Is there a way to make static calls get evaluated inside HEREDOC, possibly without assigning their values to a variable before the HEREDOC?

Comment: functions can't called inside heredocs style

Comment: @Akam I noticed only **static** functions can't be called. Regular function calls such as `$this->myCoolFunction()` return the correct result in the HEREDOC string.

Comment: I don't know, but expressions also will not be executed inside heredocs

Comment: why not just take quotes?

Comment: I would also like to see an answer for this. Seems odd that regular calls would work but static calls not work. Perhaps just naive parsing (looking for a $?) on the part of php?

Answer (score 0):

I demo a static call, but on an object.

This must be done on a recent version of PHP, they recently made it more complex.
The results of ln4 and ln5 are computed.  Is it possible to have the object, not the class?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
print("this is PHP".phpversion()."\n");
$a=1;
class b {
    public $c=3;

    public static function d() {
        return 4;
    }
}
$e=new b();

$t=<<<EOSAMPLE
hwllo world $a
ln1 {b->$c}
ln3 {b::d()}
ln4 {$e::d()}
ln5 {$e->d()}
ln2 {$e->c}

EOSAMPLE;
print($t);

$t=<<<'EOSAMPLE'
hwllo world $a
ln1 {b->$c}
ln3 {b::d()}
ln4 {$e::d()}
ln5 {$e->d()}
ln2 {$e->c}

EOSAMPLE;
print($t);

$t=<<<"EOSAMPLE"
hwllo world $a
ln1 {b->$c}
ln3 {b::d()}
ln4 {$e::d()}
ln5 {$e->d()}
ln2 {$e->c}

EOSAMPLE;
print($t);
```